# Unity3D - Parse Migration

Tags: ios, mongodb, heroku, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity3D game currently hosted on parse. I am in the process of migrating it to mongoDB and Heroku. I have followed this link [Parse Migration](https://learnappmaking.com/how-to-migrate-parse-app-parse-server-heroku-mongolab/)

Although its for iOS and I have tested it working on iOS, I am doing the same steps in Unity.

The code I am using in Unity3D is:

```
ParseClient.Initialize(new ParseClient.Configuration {
            ApplicationId = "",
            Server = "",
            WindowsKey = ""
        });
```

But nothing happens. If I initialize it like this on iOS, it works perfectly. But its not working on Unity. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A while back when I was still using Parse I was using the [ParseInitializeBehaviour.cs script](https://github.com/AngelKyriako/Parse-SDK-dotNET/blob/master/ParseCore/Public/Unity/ParseInitializeBehaviour.cs) attached in an object that persisted across scene changes.

The reason is that it does an additional call at the bottom apart from the `ParseClient.Initialize()` call.

I cannot find that script any more at current [master](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-dotNET) though.